# paint a property pane from xml schema

Tags: java, swing, xsd

We need to build a swing component to let users enter property values in a property sheet.

These properties are defined in a XSD file. For example:

```
 <xs:complexType name="email">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="body" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="from" type="tns:person" />
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="subject" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

will present user with 3 properties: Body, From and Subject in a property sheet.

[L2FProd Common Components](http://l2fprod.com/common/) has a nice component for editing properties. Before we start building ourselves, want to know if something exists already that does this.

Comment: They have a nice JWS demo: http://common.l2fprod.com/jnlp/demo.jnlp

Comment: Are you asking for other generic property editor components, or a specific one that can deal with your XSD? If the latter there probably isn't one, but it should be trivial to hook one up using Xerces in JDK (since 1.5).

Comment: @GeoffreyZheng u're right.. there's nothing pre-built. We built our own in component.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with Xerces directly.

Other possibility is use the JAXFront libraries which creates forms from a XSD ans are configurables by the developer or by the user in order to configurate the most suitable view.